# Draw two canvas using .innerHTML instead of .append()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas

I want to draw two canvas one after one, why this is not working when i use .innerHTML. On my example, only the second canva was drawn

PS : It is perfectly working with .append() of jquery , but i am not using jquery on my project

```js
<script>
document.getElementById('mydiv').innerHTML += '<canvas id="canvas1" width="50" height="50"></canvas>'
var ctx = document.getElementById("canvas1").getContext("2d");
ctx.strokeStyle = "red";
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(0,25);
ctx.lineTo(50,25);
ctx.stroke();

document.getElementById('mydiv').innerHTML += '<canvas id="canvas2" width="50" height="50"></canvas>'
var ctx2 = document.getElementById("canvas2").getContext("2d");
ctx2.strokeStyle = "red";
ctx2.beginPath();
ctx2.moveTo(0,25);
ctx2.lineTo(50,50);
ctx2.stroke();
</script>
```

```html
<div id="mydiv">

</div
```

Comment: Inspect elements. There is two canvas in div: `<div id="mydiv"><canvas/><canvas/></div>`

Comment: yes but the first one was not drawn, only the second one is drawn

Comment: Why can't use appendChild method which is I think JS method only?

Comment: Change the color of the first drawing. it draws 2 lines, one over the other, both red...

Comment: if you do not use a tag (jquery not put it between the tags of the request)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you use `.innerHTML` you actually overwrite the entire inner HTML of that element. Therefore your first canvas is no longer the canvas that your first `ctx` variable points to.

Use `var ctx = document.getElementById("id").appendChild(document.createElement("canvas")).getContext("2d")` instead to append an extra canvas without rewriting the entire DOM.

```js
var ctx = document.getElementById("mydiv").appendChild(document.createElement("canvas")).getContext("2d")
ctx.strokeStyle = "red";
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(0, 25);
ctx.lineTo(50, 25);
ctx.stroke();

var ctx2 = document.getElementById("mydiv").appendChild(document.createElement("canvas")).getContext("2d")
ctx2.strokeStyle = "red";
ctx2.beginPath();
ctx2.moveTo(0, 25);
ctx2.lineTo(50, 50);
ctx2.stroke();
```

```html
<div id="mydiv"></div>
```

To get your canvas parameters into the mix, i suggest loading the canvas into its own variable first:

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("mydiv").appendChild(document.createElement("canvas"));
canvas.id = "canvas1";
canvas.width = canvas.height = 50;
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
ctx.strokeStyle = "red";
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(0, 25);
ctx.lineTo(50, 25);
ctx.stroke();
var canvas2 = document.getElementById("mydiv").appendChild(document.createElement("canvas"));
canvas2.id = "canvas2";
canvas2.width = canvas2.height = 50;
var ctx2 = canvas2.getContext("2d");
ctx2.strokeStyle = "red";
ctx2.beginPath();
ctx2.moveTo(0, 25);
ctx2.lineTo(50, 50);
ctx2.stroke();
```

```html
<div id='mydiv'></div>
```

**EDIT - DocumentFragment**

Just for fun, you could use [DocumentFragment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DocumentFragment/DocumentFragment)s to do something like this if you really want a jQuery-like workflow:

```js
document.getElementById('mydiv').appendChild(document.createRange().createContextualFragment('<canvas id="canvas1" width="50" height="50"></canvas>'));
var ctx = document.getElementById("canvas1").getContext("2d");
ctx.strokeStyle = "red";
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(0, 25);
ctx.lineTo(50, 25);
ctx.stroke();

document.getElementById('mydiv').appendChild(document.createRange().createContextualFragment('<canvas id="canvas2" width="50" height="50"></canvas>'));
var ctx2 = document.getElementById("canvas2").getContext("2d");
ctx2.strokeStyle = "red";
ctx2.beginPath();
ctx2.moveTo(0, 25);
ctx2.lineTo(50, 50);
ctx2.stroke();
```

```html
<div id="mydiv">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use document.createElement to create your canvas.  Use appendChild instead of directly modifying innerHTML:

```js
var canvas1 = document.createElement('canvas')
canvas1.id = "canvas1"
canvas1.width = 50
canvas1.height = 50 
document.getElementById('mydiv').appendChild(canvas1)
var ctx = document.getElementById("canvas1").getContext("2d");
ctx.strokeStyle = "red";
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(0,25);
ctx.lineTo(50,25);
ctx.stroke();

 
var canvas2 = document.createElement('canvas')
canvas2.id = "canvas2"
canvas2.width = 50
canvas2.height = 50 
document.getElementById('mydiv').appendChild(canvas2)
var ctx2 = document.getElementById("canvas2").getContext("2d");
ctx2.strokeStyle = "red";
ctx2.beginPath();
ctx2.moveTo(0,25);
ctx2.lineTo(50,50);
ctx2.stroke();
```

```html
<div id="mydiv"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You think of `innerHTML` as some global string, that represents the whole HTML content as a string. Think of `innerHTML` as just one-way interface. After you put a string into it, the whole original HTML content is destroyed and the new content is built from the beginning. So after you change it, your original canvas is deleted (and replaced by a new canvas with same parameters).

I always create HTML string continuously, and then set it as `innerHTML` just once.

```js
<script>
var html = '<canvas id="canvas1" width="50" height="50"></canvas>';
html += '<canvas id="canvas2" width="50" height="50"></canvas>';
document.getElementById('mydiv').innerHTML = html;

var ctx = document.getElementById("canvas1").getContext("2d");
ctx.strokeStyle = "red";
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(0,25);
ctx.lineTo(50,25);
ctx.stroke();

var ctx2 = document.getElementById("canvas2").getContext("2d");
ctx2.strokeStyle = "red";
ctx2.beginPath();
ctx2.moveTo(0,25);
ctx2.lineTo(50,50);
ctx2.stroke();
</script>
```